# What is the unit of the coordinate system of Canvas? - android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-screen

I find that the unit of the coordinate system of Canvas is different from that of screen.

For example in my case as below:

For one particular point, its on-screen coordinate obtained from `ImageView.getX()` and `ImageView.getY()` is `(336, 578)`.

Then by trial and error, **I draw a dot on the Canvas so that this dot falls EXACTLY the same position as the ImageView.** I called `canvas.drawCircle(330, 440, radius, paint);` to achieve this.

Here comes the question:

**Why would the 2 coordinates, (336, 578) and (330, 440), different?**

Is it because the screen and the canvas use different units?

Is it an issue regarding pixel, dp and all that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting to and from window coordinates using `View.getLocationInWindow` this way you'll always be sure you are using the same coordinates system.

Coordinates of `ImageView.getX` an `Y` are relative to the parent. Canvas coordinates are relative to the view. This could cause the differences

Edit:
I assume in one place you get the coordinates of the view (using `getX` and `getY`). Convert these to window coordinates. Call these `viewXY[]`.

When you need to use them, to draw in your canvas, also convert the top and left coordinates to window coordinates. We call these `canvasXY[]`.

Now, the `X` position to draw at would be `viewXY[0] - canvasXY[0]`, and the `Y` position would be `viewXY[1] - canvasXY[1]`.

Comment: What do the window coordinates obtained from `View.getLocationInWindow` mean, please?

Comment: It seems to make much sense. How may I unify the 2 coordinates? Thanks!

Comment: I added some more description on doing that. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

A view's position co-ordinates are always relative to it's parent. It's like saying, where with respect to it's parent is this view placed.

There in another thing, screen Co-ordinate. This says where with respect to the window top/left (think actual physical screen) is this object placed. This can be obtained through `View.getLocationOnScreen`.

If you want to compare two locations, they will only be equivalent if the parent view of both these locations is same or you're using absolute screen co-ordinates. Otherwise, you'll only get results that "seem" different.

If you want to unify the two either take them to a common parent or use absolute co-ordinates.

Comment: it makes much sense. So I can draw the dot on canvas with the screen absolute location?? How may I do that? The x and y in `canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)` are simply 2 float numbers. How can I tell the function that I wanna use the screen absolute location?